# Use RxJs Pipe to reduce Observable to different type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an `Observable<Recipe[]>` that I want to reduce to an array of a different class `ChartData[]` to use as a data source for a highcharts graph (column and piechart).

I am trying to use the RxJS pipe operator on the `Observable<Recipe[]>` to call the reduce operator on my data but I cannot get it to work? The `reduce` operator does not iterate over them items in my `Observable<Recipe[]>` Below is my attempt:

```
this.foodService.getAllReceipes()
  .pipe(
    reduce((array: ChartData[], value: Recipe[], i: number) => {
        const author = this.createOrFindAuthor(array, value[i]);
        author.y += 1;

        return array;
      }, new Array<ChartData>())
  )
  .subscribe(data => this.chartData$ = of(data.sort((a, b) => b.y - a.y)));
}
```

`getAllRecipes()` returns the `Observable<Recipe[]>`

`this.chartData$` is `Observable<ChartData[]>`

I am trying to reduce this to `ChartData[]`. I have been able to do this in the `subscribe` operator and the graphs display the expected data but I thought I should be able to do it as a pipeable operator? Here is the reduce being done as part of the subscribe:

```
this.foodService.getAllReceipes()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    const list = data.reduce((arr: ChartData[], v: Recipe) => {
      const author = this.createOrFindAuthor(arr, v);
      author.y += 1;

      return arr;
    }, new Array<ChartData>());

    this.chartData$ = of(list.sort((a, b) => b.y - a.y));
  });
```

I have tried using the `subscribe` code within the pipeable `reduce` but I get compile errors saying that the method expects `Recipe[]` for the value. But if I use the array then I only get the first element from the Observable (or am I just getting the Observable and need to do something with that?)

Is this possible or is my thought process wrong about how the pipeable operator should work on the Observable?

For reference here are the models and the createOrFindAuthor function:

```
export class Recipe {

    public Title: string;
    public Author: string;
    public Source: string;
    public Page: number;
    public Link?: string;
}

export class ChartData {
    name: string;
    y: number;
}

private createOrFindAuthor(array: ChartData[], recipe: Recipe): ChartData {
  const name = (recipe.Author.length > 0 ? recipe.Author : 'UNKNOWN');

  let found = array.find(i => i.name === name);

  if (!found) {
    const newData = new ChartData();
    newData.name = name;
    newData.y = 0;
    array.push(newData);

    found = newData;
  }

  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So Chau Tran put me on the right lines. Apparently I needed to `switchMap` the Observable to a `Recipe[]` and the `reduce` operator was then happy to accept a `Recipe` as the value. Solution as follows:

```
this.foodService.getAllReceipes()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(data => data as Recipe[]),            <<== ADDED THIS

    reduce((array: ChartData[], value: Recipe) => {
        const author = this.createOrFindAuthor(array, value);
        author.y += 1;

        return array;
      }, new Array<ChartData>()),

      switchMap(data => this.chartData$ = of(data.sort((a, b) => b.y - a.y)))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

After `reduce`, try:

```
switchMap(data => {
    this.chartData$ = of(data.sort((a, b) => b.y - a.y));
    return this.chartData$;
})
.subscribe()
```

Comment: Although that improves my code it doesn't solve the problem of getting the `reduce` operator to iterate over all the items in the Observable.

Comment: You put me on the right lines, just needed an additional `switchMap` :-)

Comment: Yeah my bad, for some reason I thought you'd get the `Recipe[]` in `reduce` already.

Answer (score 0):

I created this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-reduce?file=app%2FdemoReduce.ts) to demo usage of `reduce()`. The project contains other stuff but what you need is in `demoReduce.ts`:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { reduce, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'

type Book = {
  title: string
  noPages: number
}

type Library = {
  totalPages: number
  books: Book[]
}

export const demoReduce = () => {
  const books$: Observable<Book> = of(
    { title: 'book 1', noPages: 10 },
    { title: 'book 2', noPages: 20 },
    { title: 'book 3', noPages: 30 },
  )

  return books$.pipe(
    // --- reduce a stream of "Book" into a "Library"
    reduce<Book, Library>((previous, book) => {
      // --- add book to "Library" and increment totalPages in "Library"
      return {
        totalPages: previous.totalPages + book.noPages,
        books: [
          ...previous.books,
          book
        ]
      }
    }, { totalPages: 0, books: [] }),
    tap(val => console.log(val))
  )
}
```

To execute the observable, use the "Demo Reduce" button, and look at console.

It converts a stream of `Books` into a single `Library` object.

Note:

- I am not sure why stackblitz shows error (squiggly red underline) in the online editor for `reduce()`. I did not get the error in IntelliJ/WebStorm. I suspect is a stackblitz bug.

Update:

Here's the same function that takes `Observable<Book[]>` as input (not tested):

```
export const demoReduceWithArray = () => {
  const books$: Observable<Book[]> = of([
    { title: 'book 1', noPages: 10 },
    { title: 'book 2', noPages: 20 },
    { title: 'book 3', noPages: 30 }
  ])

  return books$.pipe(
    // --- reduce a stream of "Book[]" into a "Library"
    reduce<Book[], Library>((previous, books) => {
      // --- add each book to "Library" and increment totalPages in "Library"
      books.map(book => {
        previous = {
          totalPages: previous.totalPages + book.noPages,
          books: [
            ...previous.books,
            book
          ]
        }
      })
      return previous
    }, { totalPages: 0, books: [] }),
    tap(val => console.log(val))
  )
}
```

Comment: I just realized you need "Observable<Recipe[]>" instead of "Observable<Recipe>" as input. Sorry! Anyway, I hope the demo can serve as a guide to tweak from. :-)